# Convert MSAccess Cross tab to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

TRANSFORM Min(CreateExcelForm.MinOfStockCode) AS MinOfMinOfStockCode
SELECT CreateExcelForm.FlavourCategory
FROM CreateExcelForm
GROUP BY CreateExcelForm.FlavourCategory
PIVOT CreateExcelForm.UserField2;

I wanting to convert this MSSQL any idea